# Which SE site could be used to post question on how to contact PC Gamer magazine?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I was thinking of possibly posting it in Arqade, since that covers computer gaming questions. The phone number listed in PC Magazine (for the last year or so) is 800-898-7159, but for the last several months has responded to calls as "no longer in service". The magazine is still being published; magazine racks I visit are carrying this month's edition of the magazine.

Comment: related: [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/839601)

Comment: You could try asking here: http://www.futureus.com/customer-service/

Comment: When I ask an off-topic question in one of the stack exchanges my reputation gets slammed and I am told to ask in meta instead to find where to ask the question. When I ask in meta, I my reputation gets slammed and I am told not to ask this question in stack exchange at all. Where is a list of all questions I shouldn't ask anywhere in stack exchange to avoid being slammed? I guess I should just stop asking any questions, because stack exchange is apparently extremely unfriendly to the wrong questions.

Comment: I just found http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask, but it doesn't say anything about not asking customer support questions on Meta. I'm looking for a list of all "don't ask this question" topics, like the one mentioned in gnat's comment above.

Comment: Meta is different, your reputation on meta is worth nothing. You got told that you can't ask this question on SE, so you got your answer. Move on. It is a good thing that SE is hostile against certain questions, it ensures a certain quality/atmopshere.

Comment: @polynome My objection to being slammed is not just about my reputation; if you want to prevent behavior, optimally you want to let people know not to do that behavior rather than spanking them with an axe when they do. Even if I am trying to be nice on this site, no one will tell me what the rules are. I just find out the hard way. I thought the point of stack exchange was to answer questions, such as the question of 'what questions am I not allowed to ask?' As for atmosphere, the one I notice is 'new user hostile'.

Answer (score 6):

Remember, while there are a lot of SE sites, not every topic in the world should be asked here. And even of those topics which we do have sites in (such as Arquade for gaming) there are still vast numbers of questions that would be off topic.

As gnat commented, we cannot be customer support for companies.

If contact info provided doesn't work, you can always do further research via Google - looking at company records online is always good.